Promtail scrape config dynamic file path
Promtail’s config-promtail.yml file is as follows.
scrape_configs:

job_name: dev_pg_log
static_configs:

targets:

localhost
labels:
host: dev
job:  dev_pglog
path: /app/postgres/logs/postgresql-2024-09*.log





I want to get the current date from the path here, but I don't know how. Currently, it is inconvenient to use the current month by manually modifying the file.
how can i solve this?
I want to get the current date from the path here, but I don't know how. Currently, it is inconvenient to use the current month by manually modifying the file.
how can i solve this?
